# Passing res.send value from node.js backend to react.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I am trying to pass a string from nodejs backend using res.send

```
app.post("/user", (req,res) => {
console.log(req.body.email);
res.send('haha');
});
```

I want to perform some operations based on the retrieved string value on the front end.

```
axios({ 
        method: 'post', 
        url: '/user', 
        data: { email: this.state.emailFetch } 
        }).then(response => {
            if(response.send == "haha")
            {
                return <Redirect to="/"/> 
            }
        });
```

I think I'm messing up at the handling of response at the front end. Can anyone guide me though?

Answer (score 2):

Try `response.data`, `res.send()` is just the function to send the response. You can also console log the whole response to check where the response value is stored.

Answer (score 1):

Your axios code should be like:

```
axios({ 
    method: 'post', 
    url: '/user', 
    data: { email: this.state.emailFetch } 
    }).then(response => {
        if(response.data == "haha")
        {
            return <Redirect to="/"/> 
        }
    });
```

You should read axios doc. And if you are trying to create an API you should use `res.json([])` instead in most cases

Comment: try to do ```console.log(response.data);``` above the if statement and see what it logs

Answer (score 0):

response.send is a method, so you cannot use it in frontend to extract data from it.
Easiest way for you to see whats happening on frontend side, is just console.log(response) and you can see how your response is structured and where data is contained.